# Data structure to represent functional dependencies

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm thinking about how to represent functional dependencies in as a data structure.

A functional depdendency (of a relation schema of a database) maps a set of attributes to a set of attributes. E.g. in {A, B} -> {C, D} the attributes C and D are functional dependent on A and B.

I can think of four possible cases here:

1. {A} -> {B} (two single attributes)
2. {A, B} -> {C} (a set of attributes implies a single attribute)
3. {A} -> {B, C} (a single attribute implies a set of attributes)
4. {A, B} -> {C, D} (a set of attributes implies a set of attributes)

My first approach was a simple two member class:

```
class attribute
{
    string name;
    set<attribute*> dependent_on;
}
```

This would work with functional dependencies like (1) but not with (2) - (4) - I think.
I could decompose (3), indeed, but I see no way to represent (2) and (4) with such a class.

I have to keep the information that C **and** D are functional dependent on A **and** B, so I would have to make a class like `attributegroup` where a set of attributes is mapped to a set of attributes. E.g.:

```
class attributegroup
{
    set<attribute*> members;
    set<attribute*> dependent_on;
}
```

So actually I could represent a single attribute simply as an `attributegroup` with only one member. But I do not think that this is the best way to do this.

Any help/thoughts appreciated :)

Comment: What are the specific concerns you have with the approach you suggest?

Comment: I have no specific concerns. I just think that there is a better one maybe. With my approach this will result in a `set<attributegroup>` which is just as the approach from @Dieter Lücking when it comes to implement algorithms where I have to iterate through all `attributegroup`s.

Comment: OK -- next question: what are we trying to do without having to examine all `atributegroup`s? We'll need to know what the algorithms later on want to achieve, in order to say what the data structure to enable them should look like.

Comment: The algorithms are all about the relational database theory. E.g. the canonical cover ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_cover)), the closure of attribute sets ([link](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse444/06wi/lectures/lecture09.pdf)), normal form checks / calculations. I think I have to examine all `attributegroup`s in all of them if there is no additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not store dependencies in an attribute:

```
include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct Attribute;
typedef std::vector<Attribute> Attributes;
struct Attribute {
    char name;
    operator Attributes () const { return Attributes{ 1, *this }; }
};

inline bool operator < (const Attribute& a, const Attribute& b) {
    return a.name < b.name;
}

inline bool operator < (const Attributes& a, const Attributes& b) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(
        a.begin(), a.end(),
        b.begin(), b.end());
}

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const Attributes& attributes) {
    for(const auto& a: attributes) {
        std::cout << a.name;
    }
    return stream;
}

typedef std::multimap<Attributes, Attributes> AttributeDependencies;
typedef AttributeDependencies::value_type AttributeDependency;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Attribute a {'A'};
    Attribute b {'B'};
    Attribute c {'C'};
    Attribute d {'D'};

    AttributeDependencies dpendencies;
    dpendencies.insert(AttributeDependency(a, b));
    dpendencies.insert(AttributeDependency(Attributes{a, b}, c));
    dpendencies.insert(AttributeDependency(a, Attributes{b, c}));
    dpendencies.insert(AttributeDependency(Attributes{a, b}, Attributes{c, d}));
    for(const auto& d: dpendencies) {
        std::cout << '{' << d.first << "} -> {" << d.second << "}\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: A std::map might be the right container, but std::multimap fits the example data.

Comment: Well, actually I was thinking about this kind of implementation (although I would prefer std::set over std::vector to avoid duplicates). But I had some concern concerning the runtime when it comes to implement algorithms where I have to loop over all dependencies (would be O(n^2) or am I missing something?).

So I was hoping for some kind of "weird" data structure most people would not think of.